# How to determine the country of a mobile phone browser

Tags: mobile, geolocation, mobile-website, ip-geolocation

Is it possible to determine the country of a mobile phone browser?

I've read elsewhere that mobile phone IP addresses frequently change and can be reported as originating from different countries by some IP location databases. [1](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/maheshba/papers/ephemera-imc09.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use an IP database lookup from [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location). They offer a free database & simple API which provides city level accuracy. This database is updated monthly. They also provide for a fee more accurate database's showing [metro area, corporate IP identification, ISP or NetSpeed](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolocation). The cost is very reasonable.

Bear in mind that for the IP lookup, if someone is connecting over a corporate Lan, you'll get the location of that Lan. Similarly, I've noticed that higher than expected traffic is reported as coming from Norway (the Opera Mini Browser transcoder) and Canada (RIM BlackBerry transcoders ?).